# How can I get iTerm2 to colour-code remote tmux sessions?

Tags: ssh, terminal, colors, tmux, iterm2

Currently I have a script called `et.sh`, which ssh's into a server, and integrates with iTerm2's native tmux integration to display the tmux session in native windows;

```
until ssh $1 -t "tmux -CC a -d"; do
  echo SSH disrupted, retrying in 10 seconds...
  sleep 10
done
```

However, lately, whenever I started getting multiple remotes to SSH into, I lost track of which remote was which. I want to colour-code them. I know that tmux has something wrt "`bg`", but I haven't seen a way to work this with iTerm2's native integration.

Is there a way I could colour-code these regardless? I thought of using profiles, and changing colour schemes, but there doesnt seem to be a way of systematically applying them per remote.